# Storing Images on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

How to Store Large size Images into iPhone Application?
Images are taken from UIImagePickerController but saving into Database and retrieving from
Database crash the application.

Comment: I think you need to provide a lot more information here. In particular, what is the crash? In what code? You indicate "large size images," but do small images not crash? What kind of database? How are you writing to it? There's very little information here to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are large enough, then you should NOT store them inside Sqlite. Instead, you should simply store in the database the pathname where you actually save the image in the filesystem (say for example the Documents directory of your application).

Now, it is up to you to decide what is large enough. To me, binary data greater than 1 megabyte is large enough to decide not to store the data inside the database. The threshold is dictaed by practical consideration related to the speed of both Sqlite and the filesystem.